# references in web.config vs references folder

Tags: visual-studio

I'd like to know what's the difference between adding a reference in the references folder and adding it in the webconfig file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO adding reference using the IDE would take care of copying / building DLLs if needed, while web.config check references only at runtime (application start), so adding them manually to web.config may be a less robust solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot LittleSweetSeas!